# IntelliSense not working for NuGet packages in sub-project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core, nuget, intellisense

I have an Azure Functions project with the following folder structure:

[image: VS Code folder structure]

The `SyncAgent.Data` sub-project was created with the command `dotnet new classlib --framework netcoreapp2.2`

In the same directory, I then ran `dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` to install the DocumentDB package for the `Data` sub-project.

The `DocumentRepository` class contains code to connect to a CosmosDB and add a document. The `SyncAgent.csproj` file includes the `SyncAgentData.csproj`. The Azure Function inside the `SyncPartnerCustomers` class calls code from the `DocumentRepository` class.

When executed using the VS Code debugger the code runs as expected with no errors. The problem is that IntelliSense is not recognising the `Microsoft.Azure.Documents` namespace in the sub-project.

[image: VS Code IntelliSense errors]

Why is IntelliSense failing to detect the namespace despite the fact the code runs without error?

Comment: Please refrain from putting the answer in the question.  You had it answered below.  Why did you move it into the answer?  Please undelete your answer.  You will be able to accept it later.  I have reverted your edit to the question.

Comment: @Amy no worries, have un-deleted it. It's just I've been told off by mods for doing it this way in the past. Was told that I should have edited my question. Seems whatever I do, it's the wrong thing ^^. I guess I changed it since I realised it didn't actually answer my question. It just fixed the problem. The question was "why?".

Comment: You are writing an answer to the question.  *Changes to the question*, or additional information for the purposes of getting the question answered, of course should be edited into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong but deleting all the temp `bin` and `obj` folders restarting VS Code and re-building the project seemed to fix the issue.